# Android: RTL ActionBar Menu Items

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, right-to-left

I'm using [ActionBarRTLizer](https://github.com/semsamot/ActionBarRTLizer) for making the `Home Button` and the `MenuItem`s to be from right to left instead from left to right, and i got it working in the `MainActivity` and everything is good except that when i open a `Fragment` using the `Fragment Transaction` the ActionBar returns to it's default state (LTR).

So i tried to `@Override` the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` in the fragment but it didn't work. The `ActionBar` just got messed up.(see Below screenshots

Anyone knows how to deal with that ?

Thanks in advance

**EDITED:**

This is `onCreateOptionsMenu` in MainActivity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        ActionBarRtlizer rtlizer = new ActionBarRtlizer(this);
        ViewGroup homeView = (ViewGroup) rtlizer.getHomeView();

        RtlizeEverything.rtlize(rtlizer.getActionBarView());

        if (rtlizer.getHomeViewContainer() instanceof ViewGroup) {
            RtlizeEverything.rtlize((ViewGroup) rtlizer.getHomeViewContainer());
        }

        RtlizeEverything.rtlize(homeView);
        rtlizer.flipActionBarUpIconIfAvailable(homeView);

        return true;
    }
```

And this is the overridden onPrepareOptionsMenu in the fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        ActionBarRtlizer rtlizer = new ActionBarRtlizer(getActivity());
        ViewGroup homeView = (ViewGroup) rtlizer.getHomeView();

        RtlizeEverything.rtlize(rtlizer.getActionBarView());

        if (rtlizer.getHomeViewContainer() instanceof ViewGroup) {
            RtlizeEverything.rtlize((ViewGroup) rtlizer.getHomeViewContainer());
        }

        RtlizeEverything.rtlize(homeView);
        rtlizer.flipActionBarUpIconIfAvailable(homeView);
        if(radioPlayer.isPlaying()){
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_live_stream).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_stop);
        }
    }
```

[image: This is the main action bar]

And this is after i open a fragment:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try overriding onPrepareOptionsMenu and place all the lines of code after getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); in it

Comment: I tried it but the `actionbar` got messed up, see my edited question please

Comment: Could you just have the inflater code in onCreateOptionsMenu and the remaining in onPrepareOptionsMenu

Comment: And have the onPrepare in the activity and not in the fragment

Comment: Now it works once at a time, meaning if it's RTLized and you made a Fragment Transaction it will be LTRized, and vise verse

Comment: before calling the fragment transaction try calling invalidateOptionsMenu method

Comment: Yep it works but there's a half second switching, the user can notice that the `action bar` switched to LTR then to RTL again in like a fraction of a second. It's noticeable. :(

Comment: Okay, in the activity, have the inflater and remaining RTL code in onCreateOptionsMenu and in onPrepareOptionsMenu, have only the RTL code(no inflater).

Comment: it didn't work either, do you have a good tutorial for making a custom `actionbar` ?